# `await call_next(request)` gets stuck indefinitely on larger payloads

Tags: fastapi, starlette

I got this snippet from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69669808/fastapi-custom-middleware-getting-body-of-request-inside).

When implemented,  `response = await call_next(request)` gets stuck indefinitely when the JSON payload is too large.

What could be the reason? Is it the right way to modify the body of JSON in FastAPI?

```py
class RequestContextLogMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):

    async def set_body(self, request: Request):
        receive_ = await request._receive()

        async def receive() -> Message:
            return receive_

        request._receive = receive

    async def dispatch(self, request: Request, call_next: RequestResponseEndpoint):
        await self.set_body(request)
        body = await request.body()
        jsonbody = await request.json()
        id_ = jsonbody['external_id']
        response = await call_next(request)    
        return response
```

Comment: same here. Did you find the main cause?

Comment: Yes I did. It was a mistake from my side. Reading body manually does not check for attributes like `more_body`.